# add new object to file java

Tags: java, object, save

I'm writing a program which is a console program with a menu ( 1 and 2 are the two options ) . 1 for writing an article and store it on computer and 2 for loading the articles on the computer.

My code for 1 store an article ( in articles.bin ) , but whenever new article has been written, the old one is overwritten.

Can we add a new article in articles.bin without overwriting ?

Comment: Please, share some source code so that We will be able to help you

Comment: Can you post source code for better solution, by first look it looks like you are opening new file each time you should open file in append mode. Read more about JAVA IO API.

Comment: I shared some code as a answer .

Comment: Where can I add this code ? In comments isnt enough space